# Need barcode type on scan for Honeywell Captuvo device

Tags: ios, barcode-scanner, honeywell

I'd like to get the barcode type from the SDK when I scan a barcode in from a Honeywell Captuvo device.

I'm receiving the barcode number from the following method:

```
-(void)decoderDataReceived:(NSString *) data {

NSLog(@"Decoder Data Received: %@",data);


UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"captuvo" message:data delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] ;
[alert show] ;

}
```

I've also tried the "decoderRawDataReceived" method as well, but no barcode type received.  Only the barcode number is received.

Comment: Does its API provide that info?

Comment: I can't find a method that will provide it yet.  But there are tons of methods, but still doesn't seem like it.

I'm familiar with Infinea devices and it has a method that easily gives the barcode and type using: -(void)barcodeData:(NSString *)barcode type:(int)type